# Reading Bluetooth Signal Strength

Tags: c#, java, c, bluetooth, rssi

1. Is there Any Code to read RSSI of Bluetooth Device , on Windows 7 ?
2. Which Language Should i use  : - Java -C/C++  -C# .. ?

Answer (score 2):

[readRSSI](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/com/intel/bluetooth/RemoteDeviceHelper.html#readRSSI%28javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice%29) method of Java  [bluecove.org's API](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/) may be what you are looking for. You can find an example code [here](http://bluecove.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bluecove-examples/bluecove-tester/src/main/java/net/sf/bluecove/awt/ClientConnectionDialog.java).

Answer (score -1):

Note that the built-in Microsoft Bluetooth stack has NO api for getting RSSI.  You'd need to use Widcomm, BlueSoleil, or etc...

See e.g. http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Peer%20Device%20Information&referringTitle=Documentation